# Restrict Struts2 Action to Post Method Only

Tags: java, struts2

How can we restrict a Struts2 Action to work only for `Post` method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why do you want to do this?

That aside here is how you could do it...

```
//Following has not been tested
package com.quaternion.interceptor;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

public class PostOnlyInterceptor  extends AbstractInterceptor {
    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST")){
            return Action.ERROR;
        }
        return ai.invoke();
    }  
}
```

Then build an interceptor stack for a particular package and put your actions in that package or with annotations associate your action with the package using the ParentPackage annotation.