# How to force a method to only accept POST parameters in Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2, http-post

I have the following method, which I need to force to accept only POST parameters.
This method receives id of the selected user to retrieve its object. I need to force this method to just accept posted ids not those sent by GET.

```
   public class Users{
     private long uid;

     public String show() {
            UsersModel usrModel = new UsersModel();
            return usrModel.retrieveUser(uid); //uid paramets will be sent by client to 
                                              //retrieve object of selected user
     }
     ....
   }
```

Comment: You could look at the HttpRequest and its method and refuse to work if it is not post.

Comment: Just wait for 2.3.18 https://github.com/apache/struts/pull/8 ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also create an interceptor to check for all request that you want to be only using
post methods, see the following example:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
...
request.getMethod().equals("POST") // check using this condition.
```

See the following link [Restrict Struts2 action to post method only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337383/restrict-struts2-action-to-post-method-only)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
String method = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getMethod();
if (method.equals("POST") {
    // do something
} else {}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
 if(request.getMethod().equals("POST"))
    {
             //your code
              return "accept";
    }else{
             return "not_accept";
    }
```